# JavaScript DOM - Using NodeLists and Converting to an Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, nodelist

so I will preface my question with letting you know that this is an assignment for school.  I have been working to solve this and I have tried to find the solution within the MDN documentation and I am at a loss.  I have to:

1. Grab a NodeList of bugs
2. Convert the NodeList to an Array

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bugs in the DOM</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>

    <h1>Bugs in the DOM</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Horse Flies</li>
        <li>Bed bugs</li>
        <li>Mosquito</li>
        <li>Ants</li>
        <li>Mites</li>
        <li>Cricket</li>
        <li>Woolly Bear Caterpillar</li>
        <li>Fleas</li>
        <li>Worms</li>
        <li>Leeches</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    (function() {
        // Your code here.
    }());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been able to grab the li elements, while using the DOM with the following code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
```

When i call list in the DOM, I am returned the ul, which contains all of the li elements.  Not sure if that is what I am supposed to do with respect to the NodeList.  I am also confused as to how I can convert the NodeList to an array.  Not sure if I need to use a for loop and append each element of the NodeList into a new array?  This is all still very new and confusing to me.

Any help is much appreciated, but if you are willing to share insight and an explanation, that would be ideal.  I am really trying to wrap my mind around this and I am falling short. Thank you in advance!

Comment: *use a for loop and append each element of the NodeList into a new array* - yes, exactly. You can get the `<li>` elements with `.getElementsByTagName("li");`

Comment: to convert nodeList to array use `[].slice.call(nodeList);`

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` will return an `HTMLCollection`. `document.querySelectorAll('li')` will return a `NodeList`. Note that NodeLists are immutable.

Comment: In ES6 you can use `var nodeArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate all the `<li>` items in each `<ul>` in the page like this while able to separately tell which `<ul>` they are in:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var items = list[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        console.log(items[j]);
    }
}
```

Or, if you just want all `<li>` tags, not broken out by `<ul>`:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```

A nodeList or HTMLCollection can be iterated with a simple `for` loop as seen above.  These objects do not have array methods, but can be copied into an array if you really want to use array methods.

---

Note, it is probably simpler to use `document.querySelectorAll()` for listing all the `<li>` elements and you may want to target a specific `<ul>` tag by putting an id on it in case there are other `<ul>` and `<li>` elements in the page.

```
<ul id="buglist">
    <li>Horse Flies</li>
    <li>Bed bugs</li>
    <li>Mosquito</li>
    <li>Ants</li>
    <li>Mites</li>
    <li>Cricket</li>
    <li>Woolly Bear Caterpillar</li>
    <li>Fleas</li>
    <li>Worms</li>
    <li>Leeches</li>
</ul>

var items = document.querySelectorAll("#buglist li");
for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    console.log(items[j]);
}
```

---

A nodeList or HTMLCollection can be copied into an array like this:

```
var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#buglist li"), 0);
list.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  So, I am trying to make sense of what you have going on here and I am not able to get this to run.  I am being hit with a syntax error.  I took your last section of code that converts a node list to an array and modified it to not require me to change the id of the ul in my html file:

var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"), 0);
list.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});

Comment: When I try to call list[1]; that is where I am hit with the syntax error.  I am not sure why

Comment: @DrewTuzson - make sure you have the latest code from my answer because I fixed a few typos.  And, I'm sure we could help you make your code work, but you'd have to show us exactly what code you were using.

Comment: @DrewTuzson - there is no `list[1]` in my code.  Did you mean `list[i]`?

Comment: Why not `Array.slice(`…`)`?

Comment: @Xufox - the Array object does not have a `.slice()` method.  It's on the `.prototype` or on an actual array instance.  You could do `[].slice.call(...)`, but that seems wasteful to me because it creates an empty array, just to call `.slice()` on it.

Comment: That’s weird. In Firefox 37.0.1 I can execute `Array.slice(something)`.

Comment: Here is what I'm using and this is working: 

`var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var items = list[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        console.log(items[j]);
    }
}

var newList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"), 0);
newList.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});`

Comment: @DrewTuzson - in the future, multiline code placed in comments is not readable at all.  You just can't do that and expect people to be able to read it.  You can sometimes edit it into your question and format it properly and then post a comment that tells people what you added to your question and why.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/oo9jhL4y/ for a working version of what you put in your first comment here.

Comment: When I call items[1]; that is working.  Now I am trying to alphabetize the array.  When I use items.sort(); I am being met with an error and it isnt working.  I don't understand.  items is clearly an array storing each of the li's.  When can't I sort it using sort()?

Comment: Hm, I got the `Array.slice` thing: [Array generics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods)…

Comment: @DrewTuzson - you can't sort DOM elements in that way.  If that's what you want to do, I'd suggest you ask a new question about how to sort a list of DOM elements as that involves a custom sort callback and is a different question than what you originally asked.  StackOverflow does not work well if you keep trying to add more things onto your question.  You ask what you want to ask in your question.  When that is answered, then you accept an answer to your original question (checking the checkmark to the left of the best answer) and then ask a new question for your next step.

Comment: @jfriend00 my apologies, let's try this again:
`var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");`
`for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {`
`var items = list[i].getElementsByTagName("li");`
`for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {`
`console.log(items[j]);}}`
`var newList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"), 0);`
`newList.forEach(function(item)`
`console.log(item);});`

Comment: @Xufox - `Array.slice()` is not a standard thing.  It does not exist in Chrome or IE, for example.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yep, now I know… damn, I need to change some of my code…

Comment: I hopped into the jsfiddle and that makes sense, however I am unable to call or sort the array?

Comment: @DrewTuzson - please read my prior comment about sorting.   `.sort()` by itself sorts an array of strings.  That is not what you have.  You would need a custom sort function to sort an array of DOM elements and then you would need to reinsert them into the DOM in the sorted order.  That should be the subject of a new question, not this question.

Comment: I am going to open a new question.  I am only able to post every 90 minutes, so I hope to chat with you then.  You have all be very helpful and I am very appreciative!

Comment: @DrewTuzson - I didn't know you had to wait to post a new answer.  Here's a sort solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/0ao5spgu/.  FYI, please "accept" this answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will earn both you and I some reputation points on StackOverflow which can lead to you earning more privileges here.